# Spring MVC Form Validation Does Not Work

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am following [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) to use Spring Form Validation but I cannot get the form to validate in my own program. I follow everything exactly how it's presented in the guide it just doesn't work in my application.

I used Spring Tools Suite and downloaded the sample application to see if it actually works and it does. I cannot see what exactly is causing the form validation to occur in the sample application and not mine. I tried to slowly change the sample application by removing dependencies from the POM to get it to break but it continues to work..... Which library exactly is doing the form validation?

I've seen others suggest that I need a particular validator on my classpath but the sample guide application makes absolutely no mention of this and I don't see anything special in their POM.

Controller :

```
@Controller
public class CreateEventController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/event/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(CreateEvent createEvent) {
        return "createEvent";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/event/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String checkEventForm(@Valid CreateEvent createEvent, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "createEvent";
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

Backing Bean :

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class CreateEvent {

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    private String description;
    private String password;
    private String confirm;

    // public getters and setters

}
```

Form :

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/event/create}" th:object="${createEvent}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}">Title Error</td>
            </tr>
            ... 
            <tr> for the rest of the fields 
            ... 
    </form>
```

POM :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.181</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I'm not super confident in my answer here, and therefore a comment.  I believe you actually need a library that implements the java validation framework.  I recommend looking into [hibernate validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/).  Try adding it (hibernate validator) to your pom and see if validation starts to work.  Hopefully it will.

Comment: Hibernate Validator is already included if it's Spring Boot 1.1 (via the starter-web). Not sure what log4j is doing there (it won't work and will make logback complain), but not fatal.

Comment: The guide only has 3 dependencies and one if them (at least) is redundant (hibernate validator). The validator library requires an EL implementation, so if anything would break it I'd expect it would be that (your pom doesn't explicitly have it). On the other hand the starter-web isn't very useful if it doesn't just work for validation, and I'm sure that was the intention (hence this is a comment). Hope it helps.

Comment: @hooknc, as you can see the hibernate validator is not explicitly provided as a dependency in Spring's sample application and that program still works. It does provide "tomcat-embed-el" however even upon removing this the validation still works.

Comment: @DaveSyer, so it seems the problem here is that I was only providing the NotNull annotation. The sample program has Size and Min as well. When I added an additional @Size(min=1) then the validation started to work. I think the real question is what does NotNull do?

Comment: A string never binds to null so try using @NotBlank

Comment: @SrikanthMalyala, that works! Could you please point me to the documentation that indicates a String never binds to null?

Answer (score 1):

as @hooknc suggest above. here is woring pom for validator

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- javax -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks Tung, the sample application doesn't explicitly include any validator's but it still works. See my comment to DaveSyer above...the problem is really that the NotNull annotation doesn't do anything.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. I  have not much experience about spring-boot yet.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @hooknc pointed out, apart from hibernate validator being in the classpath (pom.xml). You need to declare a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` in your beans configuration. There is a github sample post. Read this [post](https://github.com/ghillert/spring-hibernate-validator-sample) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Shazin, the sample application doesn't declare this in a bean configuration but it still works. See my comment to DaveSyer above...the problem is really that the NotNull annotation doesn't do anything.